# Why flexbox won't grow to its text?

Tags: css, flexbox, flex-grow

I need `.child-1-2` to grow to its text, but the text overflows. When I change `flex-basis` of `.child-1-1` from `50px` to `auto`, it seems to work. Why is that happening?

```css
.parent-1 {
  display: flex;
}

.child-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: #4c72af;
}

.child-1-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

.child-1-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.child-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: #f7ed7e;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-1">
  <div class="child-1">
    <div class="child-1-1">C1</div>
    <div class="child-1-2">Some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
    <div class="child-2-1">Another text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because `auto` simply allows for a smaller width with this little text content, than a fixed `50px` in combination with the `0` before it actually are. "Be as wide as you need to be, but don't shrink" and "Be 50px wide but/and don't shrink" are just that, different "formulas" saying different things.

Comment: @CBroe, you've pointed me in a direction where I found the Flex Items Formula: `content –> width –> flex-basis (limited by max|min-width)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand the reason why the described behavior takes place, we should know how `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` actually work and how width of flex items is calculated.

### Flex-grow

From [flex-grow is weird. Or is it?](https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/#article-header-id-2)

> If we apply display: flex; to the parent element and don't change
>   anything else, the child elements will be stacked horizontally, no
>   matter what. If there isn't enough space, they will shrink in size. If
>   on the other hand there is more than enough space, they won't grow,
>   because Flexbox wants us to define how much they should grow. So
>   rather than telling the browser how wide an element should be,
>   flex-grow determines how the remaining space is distributed amongst
>   the flex items and how big the share is each item receives.

### Flex-basis

Width of a flex item is determined in the following order:

1. content
2. width
3. flex-basis (limited by max|min-width)

From [The Difference Between Width and Flex Basis](http://gedd.ski/post/the-difference-between-width-and-flex-basis/)

> If no flex-basis is specified, then the flex-basis falls back to the
>   item’s width property.
>
> If no width is specified, then the flex-basis falls back to the
>   computed width of the item’s contents.

Comment: if you do a small search on the website you will also find the need answer for this as there is a lot of them well explained ...